# Forward requests by IP/Port -> local domain

Tags: networking, osx

Is there any way to forward incoming traffic to specific TLD/App by the requested port only on local network level ?

To be more specific, I'll try give an example.

For Example:

`My machine has 192.168.0.100 IP
And I can access apps like-so:
http://app-1.dev
http://app-2.dev
etc...`

`My phone has 192.168.0.101 IP
And I want to access app-1.dev on the 192.168.0.100`

So is there any way to redirect traffic like this ?:

`Request (from: phone/192.168.0.101) 192.168.0.100:3001 -> http://app-1.dev
Request (from: phone/192.168.0.101) 192.168.0.100:3002 -> http://app-2.dev`

Comment: This is unclear.  On which device do you want to do the redirection and to where?  I have the impression that you're looking for a DNS solution but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at *[socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html)*. It's a tool that establishes two bidirectional byte streams and transfers data between them.

Syntax:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:3001,fork TCP4:www.targetwebsite.com:8080
```

Where connections on port `3001` are directed to `targetwebsite.com` on port `8080`

Comment: It's kind of working, but caddy/nginx can't handle the request to 192.168.0.100:3001 and shows 404. Im going to dig in deeper and try more

Comment: @EimantasGabrielius:  I was expecting that.  You won't be able to do it that way.  You need some sort of DNS solution but to define how it can be established, you need to clarify your setup.